# If user_meta is equal to X then show a div

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, conditional-statements, meta-tags

On my site when a user is registering there is an option to pick from 3 values (House, car, boat). Once the user has registered and viewing their profile,  I want to show a button on the front-end based on what meta value they have selected when registering. If they have no meta key, then nothing is shown.

Here is my code attempt, but does not work!

```
<?php global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo(); //wordpress global variable to fetch logged in user info
$userID = $current_user->ID; //logged in user's ID
$havemeta1 = get_user_meta($userID,'house',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'house'
$havemeta2 = get_user_meta($userID,'car',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'car'
$havemeta3 = get_user_meta($userID,'boat',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'boat'

?>

<!--add if statement to figure out what button to show to logged in user-->
<?php if ($havemeta1) { ?>
   <div class="Button1"></div>
<?php } elseif ($havemeta2) { ?>
   <div class="Button2"></div>
<?php } elseif ($havemeta3) { ?>
   <div class="Button3"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div></div>
<?php }?>
```

In short -  The expected result is, if the user has choose House when registering, then show the DIV with the class=Button1 etc etc

**Update:**
This code above now works!

Comment: Please explain *does not work*. What is the result? What is the expected result?

Comment: the conditions in the if/else construction are all the same? `if($havemeta1)`

Comment: hey sorry, I rushed typing it...code fixed now...So if the user meta value "house" exists in the users profile, then I want to show button 1. If car, then show button 2, if boat, then show button 3...If none exist then show that empty div or nothing..

Comment: so what is displayed and what you want to be displayed.. or nothing is displayed...?

Comment: @Sudhir - My above code attempt is probably long winded but the best I could come up with. Basically I just want to check if (house, car, boat) exists in the users profile. If one of them exist (They can only choose 1 at registration) then I show the specific DIV listed in my code..

Comment: @MathieuImbert - edits done above, any further help now?

Comment: @Redwall We understand what you're trying to do. As far as know your code looks fine. But **what is the problem?** Do you see the wrong button? Do you see no button? Does the page break? We need to know what's wrong if you want us to help.

Comment: @MathieuImbert you are right, sorry about that, a bit of a fluster here trying to solve this. I updated the post with more details on the problem!

Comment: @Redwall A few things you can try: `echo $userID` and check that you are receiving the expected value. Then `var_dump($havemeta1)`, `var_dump($havemeta2)` and `var_dump($havemeta3)` to check their value too. It will help you figure out which part of your code is failing.

Comment: @MathieuImbert thanks for helping me. I figured out just now the code above was working as u thought.. I had another button div on the page that was absolute positioned over what I was trying to see disappear, so it looked like nothing was happening! Cheers mate...:)

Comment: @Redwall I'm glad to hear that you solved the problem :)